# How to create multiple language site when load data from database?

Tags: php

Normal, I usually define like this to create multiple languages for my site.

Like this:

```
en-en.php

define("HOMEPAGE", "Home Page");
```

---

```
vi-vi.php
define("HOMEPAGE", "Trang chủ");
```

Current, I load this menu from my database.

Has anything to create multiple language sites when load data from the database?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Google's website translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)
It's a simple plugin that allows you to convert any page to 100+ different languages live.

Comment: My customer doesn't like this. I was using this but it, not a good choice. Because google translate very ugly with my language.

Comment: You can customize how it translates words, example translating something to English might confuse the words "to" "two" or "too", you can specify which one you would like. It's all in the google dashboard.

Comment: What I mean is covered on this blog https://translate.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html

Comment: when using google translate. It will show like this: http://i.imgur.com/nwTB7Jx.png. All people don't like this.

Comment: Why don't you style the bar using CSS? Your image shows it's default style.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881361/customizing-google-translator-drop-down and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633127/can-you-style-the-google-translate-plugin

Comment: Thank you very much. I hidden it.

Comment: You're welcome! If you ever do show the bar you should also consider changing the bars colors so it suites the website colors.